# Does Trafodion support chinese charactor in Metadata?

Tags: database

I'm trying to add "comment" feature in Trafodion, and the design is to a new column "comment" in Metadata table "OBJECTS". And I'm planning to support chinese character in comment, but I'm not sure if I can do that. If yes, when I use "showddl" command to display the defination of a table, the chinese character can be displayed correctlly?

Btw, I tried to create a table with chinese character as column name, but failed.

> > create table test(名字 varchar(100));

*** ERROR[15001] A syntax error occurred at or before: 
create table test(名字 varchar(100));
                    ^ (20 characters from start of SQL statement)

*** ERROR[8822] The statement was not prepared.

> > exit

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not seeing this earlier. Right now, Trafodion requires a delimited identifier for Chinese characters. The following statement will work:

`create table test("名字" varchar(100));`

It would be nice if Trafodion would accept Chinese and other non-ASCII characters without requiring the double quotes. Feel free to file a JIRA for that.

According to the ISO/ANSI SQL standard, we should be using [Unicode General Categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:General_Category_(Unicode)) to decide which characters make up legal non-delimited identifiers, here is the relevant text:

> <identifier body> ::= <identifier start> [ <identifier part>... ]
>
> <identifier part> ::= <identifier start> | <identifier extend>

...

1. An <identifier start> is any character in the Unicode General Category classes “Lu”, “Ll”, “Lt”, “Lm”, “Lo”, or “Nl”. (NOTE 58 — The Unicode General Category classes “Lu”, “Ll”, “Lt”, “Lm”, “Lo”, and “Nl” are assigned to Unicode characters that are, respectively, upper-case letters, lower-case letters, title-case letters, modifier letters, other letters, and letter numbers.)
2. An <identifier extend> is U+00B7, “Middle Dot”, or any character in the Unicode General Category classes “Mn”, “Mc”, “Nd”, “Pc”, or “Cf”. (NOTE 59 — The Unicode General Category classes “Mn”, “Mc”, “Nd”, “Pc”, and “Cf” are assigned to Unicode characters that are, respectively, nonspacing marks, spacing combining marks, decimal numbers, connector punctuations, and formatting codes.)